# How to calculate time difference in Cassandra using Scala in Play framework

Tags: scala, time, cassandra, playframework-2.0

I am using Scala in Play framework and Cassandra as my database. I need to check a timestamp in my Cassandra database.
I have to check if this time is created more than 12 hours ago or not. If it is created more than 12 hours, then I have to update a field with a new value. I do not know how I can check this time difference in Cassandra using Scala.

Comment: What have you done so far? Your question is too general.

Comment: `def updateField(id: UUID, field: String)(implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[User] = {
    val stmt = new BoundStatement(client.session.prepare("UPDATE db.user SET field = ? WHERE id = ?;"))
    client.session.executeAsync(stmt.bind(id, field)).toScalaFuture.map(rs => user(rs.one))` in "where" I want to have something like : `where id = ? and dateof(now()) - created_time > 12 hours`

Comment: any suggestion or help for this problem?